# no acepta imagenes codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, api, rest

¿Por qué no me acepta la imagen?

***Código***

```
public function imagedata_post(){
    if (!isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
        $this->response(array('message'=>'no image'),200);
    } else {
            $date = date("Y-m-d");
            $time = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+12 hours'));
            $ram = $id."_".$date."_".$time."_".$type;

            $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            $tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
            $extension_img = end($tmp);
            $image = $ram . '.' . $extension_img;


            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '5000000';
            $config['quality'] = '20%';
            $config['file_name'] = $image;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
               $this->response(array('message'=>'ok'),200);
            }else{
                $this->response(array('message'=>'no upload file'),200);
            }
        }
}
```

***postman***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En `do_upload()` debes poner el name del input; si tu input file dice `name="img"` entonces coloca `$this->upload->do_upload('img')`

Comment: quitando las validaciones principales y dejando desde $config hacia abajo me marca `no upload file`

Comment: Puedes ver el error especifico con `$this->upload->display_errors();`, puedes ponerlo en el else.

Comment: `"<p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>"` no esta aceptando la imagen

Comment: A mi no me dio ningún (lo he replicado), asegurate de utilizar el encabezado «Content-Type: multipart/form-data» para una correcta recepción de los datos.

Comment: me sigue enviando al error a pesar de agregar el encabezado, wtf. ¿podemos iniciar un chat?

Comment: ¿te fijaste que tu formulario diga `echo form_open_multipart('tu_url')`?

Comment: estoy usando postman, debido a que es REST API

Comment: @ManuelMorales entra al chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78491/discusion-no-acepta-imagenes-codeigniter-170767

Answer (score 1):

Te falta inicializar la configuracion de `upload` haciendo uso de `$this->upload->initialize($config);` y tambien depende de como estes haciendo el envio de la imagen.

Ejemplo:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['img_1']['name'])){
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('img_1')){
            $img_1 = $this->upload->data();
        }else{
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }
```